# java extending or overriding switch cases

Tags: java, switch-statement, overriding, extend

I'm in a java course so I'm trying to be a little vague with the code so I can learn but not cheat. The assignment is to take last week's program and extend functionality. Basically, I wrote a program where I'm using switch with two cases (not sure that's the best choice, but it's what I did), and I want to add more user options. So it currently allows input 'w', 'x', but I want to add 'y' and 'z' as options by extending class A with class B.

There is a default case in the class A that basically outputs "only enter 'w' and 'x'." The problem, is even with the new B class which extends it, it prevents anything but 'w' and 'x'.

I know I need the B class to override that so it allows w, x, y, and z, and then the default triggers when anything but those *four options* are entered. Either way, help please!

Below is class A (I got rid of some of the code for my question, but all the variables, user input and scanner work. It's the cases I'm having issues with):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A {
public A()
{
  // define and implement variables
  // call scanner into existance to read inputs from the user
  // Ask for user input (abbreviated section) and store in variables

  oper = myManager.next(".").charAt(0);

  switch(oper)
    {
       // case w call to firstMethod method
       case 'w':
          DoSomething = firstMethod(num1,num2);
          System.out.println(" The result is "+FirstAns);
        break;
       // case w call to secondMethod method
       case 'x':
          DoSomethingElse = secondMethod(num1,num2);
          System.out.println(" The result is "+SecondAns);
        break;
            default:
            System.out.println(" Please Enter 'w' or 'x' only.");
      }
   /* note, this portion I got rid of some work, it's normally
      math related but modified here just to return characters for
      this post since I think it's irrelevant to my question (and I
      don't want to cheat) */

 static char firstMethod(char a)
 {
 return a;
 }
 static char secondMethod(char a)
 {
 return a;
 }
}
}
```

And below is class B which extends A, and I'm not able to convince to allow more cases. Note, after compilation, I'm executing B, but it's still only allowing the cases from A.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class B extends A {
 public B() 
 {
  // define and implement variables
  // call scanner into existance to read inputs from the user
  // Ask for user input (abbreviated section) and store in variables

  oper = myManager.next(".").charAt(0);

  switch(oper)
    {
       // case w call to firstMethod method
       case 'w':
          DoSomething = firstMethod(num1,num2);
          System.out.println(" The result is "+FirstAns);
        break;
       // case w call to secondMethod method
       case 'x':
          DoSomethingElse = secondMethod(num1,num2);
          System.out.println(" The result is "+SecondAns);
       break;
       case 'y':
          DoSomethingMore = thirdMethod(num1,num2);
          System.out.println(" The result is "+ThirdAns);
        break;
       // case w call to firstMethod method
       case 'z':
          DoSomethingLast = fourthMethod(num1,num2);
          System.out.println(" The result is "+FourthAns);
       break;
          default:
          System.out.println(" Please Enter 'w', 'x', 'y', or 'z' only.");
        }
      }
   // again, simplified this portion

 static char thirdMethod(char a)
 {
 return a;
 }
 static char fourthMethod(char a)
 {
 return a;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
 }
}
```

I then update the test program to import class B (instead of the old program which imported A since B is supposed to extend A). But it still only shows cases from A. I know it's the order of operations on how the program loads the cases, just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Use debugger. Both constructors of `A` and `B` will be called.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using a debugger. And It's not throwing any flags at me.

Comment: Put breakpoint at the start of `B` constructor and step through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default constructor of a superclass is always called first by the default constructor of the subclass.

In your example, the class A constructor is called when creating class B with the default constructor.

A solution is to move your logic into a method with the same signature in both classes and call that method in the constructor of the superclass.

Something like this:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        logic();
    }

    private void logic() {
        // Your switch of A
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super();
    }

    private void logic() {
        // Your switch of B
    }
}
```

Dynamic Binding is the OO-principle behind this solution.

Comment: aaaah, gotcha! Thank you, going to go try it.

Comment: OK, so... I have gotten it to return " Please Enter 'w', 'x', 'y', or 'z' only."

But it's doing it no matter what I enter, like wxyz all return that... But. The good news is that I was able to get it to change the switch from the old logic() with the new logic(). Now I just have to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Got it! Your code helped and I got it to replace the switch, but I mistakenly initialized num1,num2 and char again in B, which wiped out their inputs between loading A and B... Thanks for the help!